# How to fix the error in glmnet? Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size

Tags: r, glmnet

I am doing a loop.

```
all_datasets[["X19"]]
 [1] 2.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.700000e+01 0.000000e+00 2.300000e+01 1.100000e+01 1.470314e+51 0.000000e+00
[10] 0.000000e+00 7.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.830000e+02 0.000000e+00 1.324677e+11 1.000000e+00
[19] 1.200000e+01 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+01 1.300000e+01 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00


min_column_data
 [1]  5 10  7 10 11 11  4 12 17  4 14  6  6  3  3  9  2 11  7  5  5 14  2  5  8

 cv <- cv.glmnet(x = cbind(0, as.matrix(min_column_data)), y = all_datasets[["X19"]],
                 family = poisson(link = "log"), type.measure = "mse", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100, nfolds = 5)
Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Convergence for 1th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
2: Infinite objective function! 
3: step size truncated due to divergence
```

Basically, I am doing a loop. So this time is X19, next time is X20,.., etc. But sometimes I cannot can get a desired cv.glmnet.

So my first question is the above, how to fix the code. My second question is when I have such error and warning by R, what does that mean? Because my next step is to use Lasso to fit the model and get the coefficients.

```
     Fit the model
  fit <- glmnet(x = cbind(0, as.matrix(min_column_data)), y = all_datasets[[j]],
                family = poisson(link = "log"), lambda = cv$lambda.min)
```

If it means my coefficients are 0, then it is perfect. Because this should be 0, i.e., X19 doesn't have any relationship with the min_column_data.

Comment: Why not `type.measure="deviance"`? And why the constant column of 0?

Comment: What kind of data do you have where the values range from 0 to 1.4e51 ... ??

Comment: @MichaelM I am trying to follow the original paper. In the paper, the authors chose to use MSE. Also, glmnet doesn't allow to do y~x (a single x variable). Thus, I have to create a constant column of 0 to be another persudo-X1.

Comment: I see, hmm. What paper?

Comment: Oh, maybe this is the problem: You have a value of `1.470314e+51` in the response! And also `1.324677e+11`.

Comment: @MichaelM https://jmlr.org/papers/volume20/18-819/18-819.pdf

Comment: @MichaelM yes, I realize that some very large numbers. But in the original paper, it didn't give a clear way to deal with that.

Comment: These are not just very large numbers - these are errors that need to be fixed!

Comment: @MichaelM See my newest post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77594747/how-to-fix-the-warning-convergence-for-86th-lambda-value-not-reached-after-maxi    Even all numbers are generated between 0 and 100, the problem still arises.