# How to fix the Warning: Convergence for 86th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned

Tags: r, glmnet

When I use glmnet and cv.glmnet in R, sometimes I get the warning message:

```
cv <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(min_column_data), y = all_datasets[["X20"]],
                 family = poisson(link = "log"), type.measure = "mse", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100, nfolds = 5)
Warning messages:
1: Convergence for 76th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
2: Convergence for 65th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
3: Convergence for 84th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
4: Convergence for 77th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
5: Convergence for 84th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
6: Convergence for 59th lambda value not reached after maxit=1e+05 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned
```

Then I have a look at the outcome of the above.

```
cv$lambda
 [1] 3702.426406 3373.513048 3073.819447 2800.749799 2551.938906 2325.231687 2118.664513 1930.448197 1758.952499
[10] 1602.692007 1460.313267 1330.583061 1212.377729 1104.673433 1006.537290  917.119291  835.644941  761.408547
[19]  693.767111  632.134753  575.977643  524.809377  478.186758  435.705965  396.999048  361.730746  329.595584
[28]  300.315221  273.636044  249.326972  227.177451  206.995633  188.606711  171.851411  156.584605  142.674060
[37]  129.999290  118.450511  107.927694   98.339695   89.603468   81.643343   74.390373   67.781738   61.760195
[46]   56.273589   51.274399   46.719322   42.568907   38.787202   35.341454   32.201817   29.341096   26.734514
[55]   24.359493   22.195463   20.223679   18.427063   16.790054   15.298472   13.939398   12.701060   11.572733
[64]   10.544643    9.607886    8.754348    7.976636    7.268014    6.622343    6.034033    5.497986    5.009560
[73]    4.564524    4.159025    3.789548
> cv$lambda.min
[1] 3702.426
```

But I think the last lambda is much better 3.789548. I guess lambda is on the way of convergence. Am I right?

See this also:

```
 min_column_data
   X14 X12 X1 X16 X8 X4 X2 X3 X18 X19 X17 X13 X7 X9
1   16  14  3   3 11  7 10  5   6   0  13   7  1 11
2   18   6  6   4  9  7  5  4   4   5   4   6  0  8
3   22   4 18  15  3 11 12  2   3   0   2   5 45  8
4   10  22 15   7 22 11 14 15  10   5   5  25  0 18
5    8   6  3   4  7  3  6  6  29  16   5   1  0  7
6   17   8  4   3 12  4  2  2   2   0   2   2 38 66
7    5  11  6  13  8 16 20  7   3   3   3  20  0  6
8    9   4 13   7 17  7  6 16  11   1   4   1  0 11
9    8  11 17  11  7  9  9 16   5   8  13   6  0 10
10  15  12  3   3 19  2  2  5  13  12  10   7  0  0
11   9   4  8   2  2  0  4 26   3   2   2  15  0  0
12  22   4  8  16  6 10 11  8   1   7   3   3  0  5
13   3   5 14  15 10  4  9  2   5  14   2  20  0 10
14   9   4 12  23  0  8  8  8   7   5   3   4  0  8
15  15   7 12   8 12 11 12  9   7   0   2   1  0 12
16   7   2  8   3 18  3  2  7   7   4   2   7  0  0
17   6   4  3  13  3  3  2  5  12   5   2   6  0  0
18   5  14 12   2  2 13  6  3  12   0  11   6 85 17
19  17   4  7   9  6 20  6  6   2  12   8   3  0 10
20  10  11 15  14  5  2  3 24   3   2   4   5  0 26
21   4   8  5   9 13 10 18  2   4  13  15   4  0 17
22  18   7  6   6  4  6 20 18   4   4  18  14  0 11
23   4   4 22  16  3  8  4  2   6   5   4  15  0 16
24  11   9  5   5  3 18  1 11  18   4   3   5  0 12
25   5   8  3  12  6  1  4  6  10  14   1   5  0  8
> cv <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(min_column_data), y = all_datasets[["X20"]],
+                 family = poisson(link = "log"), type.measure = "mse", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100, nfolds = 5)
```

Even all numbers all between 0 and 100, it still sometimes says that glmnet.fit: algorithm did not converge. Why it happens?

Comment: My last comment on this problem is: No, `lambda` is simply the value of the penalty. The performance is in slot `cvm`, which you will see is worsening. I suggest to read the original glmnet paper and the package documentation to really understand what `cv.glmnet()` and `glmnet()` do. It will be worth a lot to gain trust into the technique. Blindly applying algorithms is not a good strategy.

Comment: you haven't shown us what `all_datasets[["X20"]]` is, AFAICS, so this example isn't reproducible ...